# Reading a SOAP header to a SOAPpy response?

Tags: python, soap, soappy

How can I read s SOAP header from a SOAPpy response?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, without modifying SOAPy.

When you call a SOAP method, SOAPy runs its own `request` function, which returns a valid [HTTPResponse](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httpresponse-objects) object. However, it does not retain that object; within the same method call, it parses the body, and returns the result.

In order to alter this behaviour, you'll want to look at the `__call__` method of the `Method` class in soap.py.